# I want to know if beet juice without the beets is available for making pickled eggs

Tags: juice

We have been making pickled eggs recently.  To do that we buy cans of cooked beets and just use the juice in the recipe.  It is a waste of the beets (you can only eat just so many cooked beets).  Is there a source for JUST beet juice?  The only products I am able to find are of the health food variety and they have other things in  them such as carrots and other vegetables.

Comment: What are they supposed to do with all the dry beets? ;)

Comment: Or go the other route, and find ways to use up all of the beets : http://www.foodandwine.com/blogs/2014/05/05/15-ways-to-use-beets

Comment: I suggest you add a country/region tag (unless you're willing to buy worldwide)

Comment: @JanDoggen we don't have country specific tags. There are tags like [tag:french-cuisine], but they describe the cooking method origin, not the current location of the OP.

Comment: @rumtscho Ah OK, thanks. J. Cook can [edit] it into the text then.

Answer (score 2):

The "juice" in a jar of pickled beets is pickle brine and flavors leached from the beet by the vinegar. To replicate in bulk, without wasting a lot of beets, make a batch of pickle brine following any recipe that tickles your fancy (lots of them on the internet!), and then add beet puree or juice to suit. You can make your own puree by roasting, blending and then straining beets, and juice by doing the same to the beets raw - or just send them through a juicer if one is handy.

Answer (score 1):

Love Beet juice is available in the UK, 99% beetroot juice, 1% lemon juice.

In the US from what I can see its mostly adulterated, however you can buy beet juice in a concentrated form which claims to be [100% Beet juice.](http://www.juiceconcentrates.us/beet-juice-concentrates-usa)

Answer (score 1):

Correct me if I am wrong, but I believe the only function of beet juice in pickled eggs is as a colorant (even if this is not true, you could still do the following).  It would be fairly easy and inexpensive to purchase a small amount of beetroot, cook it, then puree it in the blender with some water.  This could be strained and used in your recipe.